# svn txn-current-lock permission denied

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I had a subversion checked out to /home/svn/docs, then i chose to use a different path, removed that dir with rm-rf and checked out a new repository to my home/user/docs dir. that worked fine. If i now want to commit something it says:

svn: Can't open file '/home/svn/docs/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied

I am running ubuntu

Comment: Have you found the resolution? The answer we have here doesn't works, as we don't have repository under old path more.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like your subversion **repository** is present in `/home/svn/docs` and you do not have write permission.  Possibly the repository is created as a different user and the commit is being done as a different user.

One way to address this is by ensuring all subversion users belong to the same **group** and this group has **write** access to the repository folder.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I've moved my repository completely. The path this error message refers too doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: @webdevbyjoss.  Can you post more details of your problem as a new question so that it gets attention and someone can respond?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same proble. using windows. I tried to give Full control to Everyone, but still id did not work out.

I tried to rename txn-current-lock to txn-current-lock.xxx and write-lock to write-lock.xxx and it worked. I guess these files were locking and causing the error in the first place and even deleting them would solve the issue.

DO NOT DELETE txn-current because it is needed by svn though.

Btw, i found an article here http://cloudspring.com/how-to-use-dropbox-with-svn-or-git-for-cloud-source-control-management/ explaining how to use dropbox and svn to create a 'distributed scm' and I currently experimenting with this, that is how I have ancountered this problem. Usually svn works fine immidiately.

Comment: I think one way is to simply delete `txn-current-lock` and `write-lock`, though I wonder how they were created in the first place and why they weren't deleted.

By the way, I tried renaming and deleting both lock files, neither solved the problem on Linux. I wonder if the real answer lies elsewhere...